# DataGridColumnHeader CheckBox IsChecked Binding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

It is all - part of the UI, `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface of cource implemented, all `Bindings` work fine. But by some reason one `Binding` does't work. Here it is.

```
IsChecked="{Binding ArchiveDocsLinkedChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

This is my XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                  <CheckBox Margin="0,2,3,0" Checked="ArchiveDocsLinkedMainCheckBoxChecked"  Unchecked="ArchiveDocsLinkedMainCheckBoxUnchecked" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsChecked="{Binding ArchiveDocsLinkedChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                     <CheckBox.ToolTip>Выделить все/Снять выделение</CheckBox.ToolTip>
                  </CheckBox>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="theCheckbox"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And this is my code-behind field + property:

```
private Boolean _archiveDocsLinkedChecked
public Boolean ArchiveDocsLinkedChecked
{
    get
    {
        return _archiveDocsLinkedChecked;
    }
    set
    {
        _archiveDocsLinkedChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ArchiveDocsLinkedChecked");
    }
}
```

I suppose it is because of `Binding` is within Template of DataGridColumnHeader. And it is not pretty standart situation for bindings. How can I specify that `Binding` properly? thx!

Comment: Check output window for any binding errors. They will guide you why it was failing.

Comment: In output window i see nothing about this `Binding` :(

Comment: Please remove your last question update and add it as an answer, so that this question can have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem.

Binding must looks like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                                                                Path=ArchiveDocsLinkedChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Obviously, when you are in `ControlTemplate` you are within `DataContext` of `ControlTemplate`. So you must go upper to get access to `Window's` `DataContext` :)

p.s. why, when I copy&paste some code it appears shifted to right side? ctrl+K doesn't solve that, and I forced adjust code manually...